# I have a table where i need to select the max value of one column

Tags: sql

Ive found a couple solutions [one in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql) that was of great help, and nearly got me there, but im stuck on the last bit. All i need to do now is be able to specify a range for the CarNumbers to be displayed.

the SQL might make more sense...

```
SELECT sr.*  FROM StatusReport sr 
INNER JOIN (  SELECT CarNumber, MAX(StatusReportTime)  AS MaxDateTime
FROM StatusReport  GROUP BY CarNumber )  groupedsr ON sr.CarNumber =
groupedsr.CarNumber  AND sr.StatusReportTime = groupedsr.MaxDateTime
```

I basically want to be able to add the following line in.

```
WHERE CarNumber BETWEEN '0' AND '3999'
```

Could anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: what rdbms youare using? MySQL? SQLServer? Oracle? ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it at the end of the outer query, or at the end of the subquery before the `GROUP BY` clause like so:

```
SELECT sr.*  
FROM StatusReport sr 
INNER JOIN 
(  
  SELECT CarNumber, MAX(StatusReportTime)  AS MaxDateTime
  FROM StatusReport  
  WHERE CarNumber BETWEEN '0' AND '3999'
  GROUP BY CarNumber 
)  groupedsr  ON sr.CarNumber        = groupedsr.CarNumber  
             AND sr.StatusReportTime = groupedsr.MaxDateTime;
```

Comment: Also could do it by `HAVING` in the `INNER JOIN` subquery.

Comment: thanks so much for all the answers, it makes alot more sense to me now. thanks again!

Comment: @jdotjdot - Yes you are right. But since you are not filtering on the aggregated column something like `HAVING MAX(status) < ...` then it is better to do this using a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ok so further more i have another question. When i run the query, it works fine when i look for say 0 - 3999, but when i search 7101-7199 i get results as follows: 7, 71, 711, 7189 etc. it seems to be searching through each digit in the query. i specifically need just 7101-7199.

Comment: @user1952458: Is it an integer? Use integers, not strings. `BETWEEN 7101 AND 7199`

Comment: @user1952458 What is the datatype of that column `CarNumber`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sr.*
FROM StatusReport sr
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT CarNumber,
          MAX(StatusReportTime) AS MaxDateTime
   FROM StatusReport
   WHERE CarNumber >0
   GROUP BY CarNumber) groupedsr ON sr.CarNumber = groupedsr.CarNumber
AND sr.StatusReportTime = groupedsr.MaxDateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.. this will be easy to understand and will simplify your query

```
    with tbl2 as
    (
    select tbl1.*,
    row_number() over (order by CarNumber) rtn 
    from 
    (select CarNumber, max(StatusReportTime) as MaxDateTime from [StatusReport] group by         
    CarNumber) as  tbl1
    )
    select  * from tbl2 where rtn between 0 and 3999
```